# Uniswap read contract (klast, getReserves, price0CumulativeLast, price1CumulativeLast)

Tags: tokens, uniswap

https://etherscan.io/address/0x3139Ffc91B99aa94DA8A2dc13f1fC36F9BDc98eE#readContract

I'm trying to understand what data these function output: klast(), getReserves(), price0CumulativeLast(), price1CumulativeLast().

I'm assuming *price0CumulativeLast* & *price1CumulativeLast* are the latest prices of their respective token in Ether.

*getReserves* I believe is the liquidity of the respective token in Ether.

kLast i have no guess what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `price0CumulativeLast` and `price1CumulativeLast` are indeed the latest prices of their respective tokens in Ether.
- `getReserves` is a function that returns the current liquidity of both tokens and the timestamp of the last liquidity event.
- `kLast` is a public variable that stores the product amount of the first token and the second token as of immediately after the most recent liquidity event. It may be useful in calculating the current price of the tokens being traded.

Answer (score 0):

The kLast function likely returns the latest value of the "k" variable in the smart contract. Without more context about the specific contract and its intended use, it is difficult to say for certain what the k variable represents.

getReserves function returns the total liquidity of the respective token in wei.

price0CumulativeLast and price1CumulativeLast likely return the latest cumulative prices of the respective tokens in wei. It can be assumed that it is the price of the token in ether.